# Contact Form 7 - Selectable recipients with pipes not sending correct values

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a problem when using selectable recipients with pipes in Contact Form 7 (CF7).

Code

```
[group loc1]
[md-select label="department"][select* dept-loc1 include_blank
"Machine 1|testperson1@test.com"
"Machine 2|testperson2@test.com"
"Machine 3|testperson3@test.com"
"Machine 4|testperson1@test.com"
[/md-select]
[/group]

[group loc2]
[md-select label="department"][select* dept-loc2 include_blank
"Machine 5|testperson3@test.com"
"Machine 6|testperson1@test.com"
"Machine 7|testperson3@test.com"
[/md-select]
[/group]
```

*The md-select tag is for the Material Design plugin.*

If I select "Machine 4" in Location/Group 1, an email will be sent to "testperson1@test.com" but with content "Machine 1" instead of "Machine 4". In Location/Group 2 it is the same problem. If I select "Machine 7", an email will be sent to "testperson3@test.com" with content "Machine 5" instead of "Machine 7".

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you getting the email by tag `[_raw_dept-loc1]`?

Comment: Yes, the TO field is filled with `[_raw_dept-loc1], [_raw_dept-loc2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use email aliases to overcome this issue, try this instead:

```
[group loc1]
[md-select label="department"][select* dept-loc1 include_blank
"Machine 1|testperson1@test.com"
"Machine 2|testperson2@test.com"
"Machine 3|testperson3@test.com"
"Machine 4|testperson1+4@test.com"
[/md-select]
[/group]

[group loc2]
[md-select label="department"][select* dept-loc2 include_blank
"Machine 5|testperson3@test.com"
"Machine 6|testperson1@test.com"
"Machine 7|testperson3+7@test.com"
[/md-select]
[/group]
```

I know the `+` addition works on gmail, I haven't tried with other emails.  If it does not work with your email domain server, then you will need to create [email aliases](https://simplelogin.io/blog/email-alias-vs-plus-sign/) for those email addresses you want to use multiple times within your field, one alias for each extra use.

Comment: With Gmail it works indeed fine, however our internal MS Exchange server does not receive those emails. But I will find a solution with email aliases. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: you're wc.  You could use your web server mail service with a mail forwarding setup to the actual address, this is easy to setup on cpanel server managed system, no emails will be stored and instead forwarded to the actual recipient.