# Selectable recipient with pipes contact form 7 get country name issue

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7

I am using country dropdown in my contact form 7. it look like this `[select* country "Canada | team1@website.com,team3@website.com" "Mexico | team2@website.com" "Zimbabwe | team3@website.com"]`, It is working fine if I am using it to get first value by [_row_country] and second value (after pipe) by [country] in mail section.
But I want to save it in customer database and tryin to get country name by this

```
$your_country = $form_data['_raw_country'];
$country = implode( ', ', (array) $your_country );
```

it return only email but not country, So I also try this

```
$your_country = $form_data['country'];
$country = implode( ', ', (array) $your_country );
```

It return blank.
This is my Code for reference.

```
function contactform7_before_send_mail( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {
    // set your db details.
    $mydb = new wpdb( 'user', 'password', 'database', 'localhost' );
    if ( $submission ) {
        $form_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        $your_country = $form_data['_raw_country'];
        $country = implode( ', ', (array) $your_country );
        $mydb->insert(
            'tableName',
            array(
                'fullname'        => sanitize_text_field( $form_data['FullName'] ),                
                'country'         => $country,
                'companyname'     => sanitize_text_field( $form_data['CompanyName'] ),
                
            ),
            array( '%s', '%s', '%s' )
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'contactform7_before_send_mail', 10, 3 );
```

this is the reference link https://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/

Comment: Another option how to solve this issue can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69618595/contact-form-7-selectable-recipients-with-pipes-not-sending-correct-values

Answer (score 0):

To get the information from the pipes, you can't just use the `[_raw_field]` since it's not stored that way.  It's a little more complicated to get the value of the Piped data.  To get the value of the pipes, you have to retrieve the form tags, then loop through the pipe values for each.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'dd_handle_form_submission', 10, 3 );
function dd_handle_form_submission( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {
    if ( $submission ) {
        $form_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        // Get the tags.
        $tags = $submission->get_contact_form()->scan_form_tags();
        // Get the country field submission.
        $country = $submission->get_posted_data( 'country' );
        foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
            if ( 'country' === $tag->name ) {
                // Get the Pipes.
                $pipe_array = $tag->pipes->to_array();
                foreach ( $pipe_array as $value ) {
                    if ( $country[0] === $value[1] ) {
                        // $value[0] is Left of Pipe - $value[1] is right of pipe.
                        $country_name = $value[0];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if ( isset( $country_name ) ) {
            $mydb = new wpdb( 'user', 'password', 'database', 'localhost' );
            $mydb->insert(
                'tableName',
                array(
                    'fullname'    => sanitize_text_field( $form_data['FullName'] ),
                    'country'     => $country_name,
                    'companyname' => sanitize_text_field( $form_data['CompanyName'] ),

                ),
                array( '%s', '%s', '%s' )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**New Answer / Solution to Specific Problem**

In your case, the values after the pipes are not unique.  This poses another issue all together, which makes pipes less than awesome.  In this case, I would use jQuery and a hidden form field.

Make the contact form something like this:

```
<p>[select* country id:country include_blank "Canada | team1@website.com,team3@website.com" "Mexico | team2@website.com" "Serbia | team2@website.com" "Zimbabwe | team3@website.com"]</p>

<p>[text FullName]</p>
<p>[email your-email]</p>

[hidden hidden_country id:hidden_country]

[submit]

<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $('#country').on( 'change', function() {
            $('#hidden_country').val($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then since you're just capturing the country value on change, you can easily push that value to your database, and your email to (the right of the pipes) is used, and that's that.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'dd_handle_form_submission', 10, 3 );
function dd_handle_form_submission( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {
    if ( $submission ) {
        $form_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        $country_name = sanitize_text_field( $form_data['hidden_country'] );
        if ( ! empty( $country_name ) ) {
            $mydb = new wpdb( 'user', 'password', 'database', 'localhost' );
            $mydb->insert(
                'tableName',
                array(
                    'fullname'    => sanitize_text_field( $form_data['FullName'] ),
                    'country'     => $country_name,
                    'companyname' => sanitize_text_field( $form_data['CompanyName'] ),

                ),
                array( '%s', '%s', '%s' )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working only when email ids are different for all countries. But In my case for some country email id different and for other, email id same like [select* country "Canada | team1@website.com,team3@website.com" "Mexico | team2@website.com" "Serbia | team2@website.com" "Zimbabwe | team3@website.com"], It return Serbia if select  Mexico

Comment: The email IDs are the same.  Of course it returns the last one in the data set.. how do you now which one they chose, if the recorded value is the same?  This is able to be resolved, but it's really another question.  What I have shown you here - answers how to get the pipe values.

Comment: I was posted question before also. but at that time not get luck. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699300/contact-form-7-country-name-with-pipe-symbol-not-work-after-post-request

Comment: I gave you an answer there also.

Comment: Yes but at that time, Issue was same. and still I am not getting the solution of my issue

Comment: The values that are to the right of the pipes are not passed to the contact form at all, even though that is the data passed in the submission. So to match up values based on chosen data to the right of the pipe, it must also be unique to other values to the right of the pipe.  So to work around this, you could create another sub-routine to `$contact_form->set_properties()` and push the mailto address this way rather than use pipes at all.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Can you please explain me in my code, what you want me to change. I have created country dropdown in my code in contact form 7 like this [select* country "Canada | team1@website.com,team3@website.com" "Mexico | team2@website.com" "Serbia | team2@website.com" "Zimbabwe | team3@website.com"]  . Can you please explain it by code.

Comment: I've added an alternate solution.  You can move the jQuery to an external file, or use `wp_add_inline_script` if you really want to.  If you get a bunch of auto p tags in the script, just minify it manually.